# Quoted string in CSV input become double-escaped

Tags: json, csv, jq

I'm trying to use JQ to process CSV like this which has no column headings:

```
cat "input.csv"
"12345678901234567890","2019-03-19",12
```

**Is there more elegant and readable way to remove escaped quotes for the first and second fields--and overall, to build a stream of objects given such input?**

---

Ideally I would like to have a reusable script which builds JSON from an artbitrary CSV, given a file and a list of fields in it passed as a command-line argument.

Current JQ script and output:

```
cat "input.csv" |
jq \
  --raw-input '
    . |
    split("\n") |
    map( split(",")) |
    .[0] |
    {
      ID: (.[0] | fromjson),
      date: (.[1] | fromjson),
      count: (.[2] | tonumber)
    }'

{
  "ID": "12345678901234567890",
  "date": "2019-03-19",
  "count": 1
}
```

Output of the same script without `| fromjson` used which results in quoted quotes, which I would like to avoid:

```
{
  "ID": "\"12345678901234567890\"",
  "date": "\"2019-03-19\"",
  "count": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your invocation of jq can be simplified to:

```
jq -R '
  split(",")
  | map(fromjson)
  | {ID: .[0], date: .[1], count: .[2] }'
```

### Generic solution

```
jq -R --argjson header '["ID", "date", "count"]' '
  split(",")
  | map(fromjson)
  | [ $header, . ]
  | transpose
  | reduce .[] as $kv ({}; .[$kv[0]] =$kv[1]) '
```

If you want to specify the headers in a file, use the `--argfile` command-line option instead.